# How to build custom @Projections for spring-rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-rest

`spring-data-rest` makes it possible to expose `@Entity` domain objects directly and even provide a `DTO` projection as follows:

```
@Projection(name = "personDTO", types = { Person.class })
public interface PersonDTO {

  @Value("#{target.firstName} #{target.lastName}") //SPeL
  String getFullName();
}
```

Question: what if I want to construct only *some* of the dto fields myself? Eg having some kind of condition on the firstname field, and fill it based on this either the one or other way. Is that possible?

Spring mentions a example, but unfortunately it's not complete:
https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra

```
@Projection(name = "summary", types = Order.class)
interface OrderSummary {
  @Value("#{@shop.calculateTotal(target)}")
  Money getTotal();
}
```

Here the logic is exported to `@shop.calulcateTotal()`, BUT they don't tell in the example how this `@shop` bean is injected here. I assume this is a  `@Service`, but don't know how to get it in.

Answer (score 0):

Says right below the example you posted.

https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra

> For advanced use cases you can even equip the projection methods with @Value to return the result of a SpEL expression to the marshaller. In our sample here, we invoke a method on a Spring bean named shop and hand the proxy target instance to it to calculate the order total, which could consider rebates, taxes etc.

Since your projections are already managed by spring, you don't really need to inject it.  Spring magic takes care of it for you.

Comment: Yes, but how can I know which bean maps to `@shop`?

Comment: Did you try it out?  I haven't tried, but I'm guessing whatever bean has an id of shop.  You could probably use @Qualifier as well.